# Spring MVC, call method when view is closed

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Is possible using spring MVC to call a method from the controller when the view (page) is closed ?

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC is based on Request and Response and does not know about the state of your view / browser.
As a workaround you could use Javascript and register a request to your application. The event that you are looking for is `window.onbeforeunload` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload))